# Newsletter subscribed variable in success.phtml

Tags: magento-1, newsletter

I am looking to show a custom message to customers who subscribed to newsletter on the checkout confirmation page on our magento site but I am not able to check the subscription status using the following method in `success.phtml`:

```
<?php 
$customerSession = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");
$email = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail();
$subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);

$status = $subscriber->isSubscribed();  // status should be  1 if subscribed.
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code this may help

```
  $subscriber = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->loadByEmail($email);
  $status = $subscriber->getSubscriberStatus();//This will be 1 if user subscribed
```